# Connect , query and while with 2 or more databases

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to open a connection with 4 databases (same host). all 4 looks same.

here's my code, but i get no output. why? anyone has a solution?
maybe my query is not correct?

thank you!

```
 <?php 

 $db = new mysqli("localhost","username","password");

 mysqli_select_db('database1', $db); 
 mysqli_select_db('database2', $db); 
 mysqli_select_db('database3', $db); 
 mysqli_select_db('database4', $db); 


 $query = "SELECT A.name AS name1, 
                  B.name AS name2, 
                  C.name AS name3, 
                  D.name AS name4 
        FROM database1.table1 A, 
             database2.table2 B, 
             database3.table3 C, 
             database4.table4 D"; 
 $result = $db->query($query);

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo $row['name1'];
 echo $row['name2'];
 echo $row['name3'];
 echo $row['name4'];
 } 

?>
```

Comment: Do all daabases have same uid/pwd

Comment: yes! all on the same server, same host, username, password

Comment: What's the point of calling `mysqli_select_db()` 4 times? The first 3 are useless.

Comment: How big are the tables? You're creating a full cross product between all of them, so the size of the result will be the product of all their sizes. E.g. if they each contain 100 rows, that's 100,000,000 rows.

Comment: @tadman What variables are you talking about?

Comment: @Barmar each of them around 400 rows.. :(

Comment: You probably need a joining condition to get related rows between the tables.

Comment: @PatrickDukeSchauer Then the result will be 25,600,000,000 rows. It will take forever to print all the results.

Comment: @tadman But he's joining all the tables in one query, not using separate connections for each table.

Comment: The purpose of this cross-product is really not clear. That's way too many combinations to be meaningful.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I'll edit.

Comment: You're unnecessarily mixing and matching the procedural and object-oriented styles. The object-oriented one is considerably less verbose, so just stick with that. `$db->select_db('name')`

Comment: @Barmar .. the idea was only to list the name of the 4 tables from the 4 db's in one query! then this solution(!) is not really effective..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You don't need to perform a query to list the names of the tables, they're just `table1`, `table2`, etc. If that's not what you mean, show some sample table contents and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: I think you need to read a basic SQL tutorial on JOINs. The fact that they're in different databases is irrelevant to how you combine the table contents.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i have my solution. One connection, only the query... ! thanks for the hints guys!

```
$query = "
SELECT database1.table1.name as name FROM database1.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT database2.table2.name as name FROM database2.table2
UNION ALL
SELECT database3.table3.name as name FROM database3.table3
UNION ALL
SELECT database4.table4.name as name FROM database4.table4 order by name";
```